# Adding an icon left of primaryText in Material UI's <ListItem>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a `<ListItem>` from React Material UI that currently has a checkbox to the left. I want to add an image/icon in between the checkbox and the title (or rather, to the left of the title) and after looking at the docs, I'm unsure if this can be achieved.

[image]

I want to do something like:

[image]

This is easily achievable in `<Table>` with multiple row columns - is there something similar in ListItems? I see `leftIcon` on the docs but it isn't working.

```
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox'

render() {
    <ListItem 
        primaryText="autoblog.com" 
        leftCheckbox={<Checkbox />
        rightToggle={<div style={{display: 'none'}} />}
    />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, put the image inside `leftCheckbox`:

```
leftCheckbox={  <div>
                    <Checkbox />
                    <img src='https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg'/>
                </div>
}
```

Apply `css` to position the image correctly.

Check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/fjn86nxq/)**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I thought of another solution - render a div inside `<ListItem>` as children. What do you think?